# Easy way to style link colour separate from a:link

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

I am currently using:

```
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But on a certain page in my website I want to be able to have my links in a separate colour.

What is the best way to do this through CSS?

I don't want to do:

```
<font color="#00FF00">...</font>
```

As i know this is deprecated code

Comment: Add a css `class`? `.alternate-colour {color:#00FF00}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to every link you want to affect:

**HTML:** `<a href="#" class="alternate">Link</a>`

Then add this CSS or similar to your style sheet:

**CSS:** `a.alternate {color:#00FF00;} //or whatever`

Demo: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/Aalkb

Answer (score 0):

apply different `class` attribute to that `link`. for ex:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="red">link1</a>
<a href="#" class="black">link2</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.red{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.black{
    color: #000000;
}
```

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv3yk/)

Comment: this doesn't work as I have already got a link colour set in the CSS.
I wanted to be able to override the link colour on just one page for another colour

Comment: go on that FIDDLE, which i provided and see..it works finely, May be there other issue in your code.

Comment: No, I see where your code works but as I have already got colour set in my css I didn't want to have to change it to work the way your example does.

@harley's code worked right for me.